# contact search for android

Tags: java, android, contacts, android-contacts

I am trying to get the code to search for exchange and gmail contacts.
But I ended up only with code for searching local address book.

```
public void contactSearch(String name)
{

    name=name.toLowerCase();

    ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();

    Cursor c = resolver.query(
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            ContactsContract.Data.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "!=0 AND (" + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=? OR " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?)",
            new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE},
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID);

    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME)).toLowerCase().contains(name)||c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1)).contains(name)) {
            Log.w("All contacts Data", getdetails(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME)), c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1))).toString());
        }
    }
    c.close();
}

public HashMap<String,String> getdetails(String name,String email)
{
    HashMap<String, String> contactDetail = new HashMap<String, String>();
    contactDetail.put("name", name);
    contactDetail.put("email", email);
    return contactDetail;
}
```

Can someone tell me how to search for Exchange and GMail contacts if user is not present in local contacts directory?

Comment: I found the api for exchange and google.

Comment: Can you share the api link. If you've found the answer do share it. It may help someone.